# Reversing a Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse

I am supposed to reverse the order of a linked list, and I think I got the right idea, but for some reason, my code is entering an infinite loop when I print out the list and I'm not sure why I think it has something to do with the for loop near the end, because when I comment that part out and test it again, there's no infinite loop anymore.

This is an example of what a list might look like:

```
42, 36, 14, 17, 48, 36
```

And this is what I'm trying to get:

```
36, 48, 17, 14, 36, 42
```

And below is my code:

```
// List element: a list is a chain of these
typedef struct element
{
  int val;
  struct element* next;
} element_t;

// List header - keep track of the first and last list elements
typedef struct list
{
  element_t* head;
  element_t* tail;
} list_t;



void reverse (list_t* L)
{
  //getting the len of the list
  unsigned int len = 0;
  element_t* temp = L->head;
  while (temp != L->tail)
  {
    len++;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  len++; //extra +1 len for tail since while loop does not include


  //now for reversing 
  unsigned int i = 0;
  element_t* ELEtail = L->tail;
  element_t* ELEhead = L->head;
  for (i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
  {
    ELEtail->next = ELEhead;
    ELEhead = ELEhead->next;
    ELEtail = ELEtail->next;
  }

}
```

Comment: I kind of liked how happy you were about "being new to C!". I think the edit was fine before :P

Comment: If you visualize the elements of the list as blocks with the pointers being arrows, can you guess why the program might enter an infinite loop?

Comment: There should also be zero need to walk the list to determine length for this. This exercise is all about pointer management.

Comment: You should be able to do this in a single iteration across the list if you think about basically swapping the direction of the link at each node. That is instead of `parent -> child` you make `parent <- child`. And then at the last step swap head and tail.

Comment: To reverse a linked list there is no need to traverse the entire list. It is enough to traverse **N/2**, **(N/2)-1** iterations if the length of list is even, odd numbers respectively.

Comment: Ahaha I actually had a "Hello!" before that "new to C!" thing, but it got erased somehow, so I tried adding it back in but then it erased my new to C part too, so I was like...o.o I guess I'll just leave it then haha.

Comment: lol disregard this comment. xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you write in your for loop is wrong.

To give you an idea let us take your example. Initially your list is

```
42 -> 36 -> 14 -> 17 -> 48 -> 36
|                             |
ELEhead                    ELEtail
```

Just before the for loop: ELEtail  points to  36 (last element) and ELEhead points to 42 (first element).

Now after the first iteration of your for loop : ELEtail points to 42 and ELEhead points to 36(second element of initial list) and the list becomes

```
42 -> 36 -> 14 -> 17 -> 48 -> 36 -> 42
 |                                   |
ELEhead                           ELEtail
```

First and the last 42 in above example are same element. Hence it makes an infinite loop.

Now to reverse the link list, you require only one pointer for the head of the reversed linklist. Every time you encounter a new element in the original linklist just enter it at the head of the reversed linklist. And your linklist will be reversed when you insert the last element of original linklist at the head of the new linklist. And for that you don't even require to know the length of the original list. This will save your first loop where you are calculating the length of the linklist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on, you don't need to know the size of your list or loop.

```
void reverse_list(list_t* l) {
    element_t* new_tail = l->head;
    element_t* new_head = reverse(l->head); //Assumes l isn't NULL!
    l->head = new_head;
    l->tail = new_tail;        
}

element_t* reverse(element_t* head) {
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (list->next == NULL)
        return head;
    element_t* body = reverse(head->next);
    head->link->link = head; // reverse head
    head->link = NULL;
    return body;
}
```

Comment: Great. Now try it with a list of 500,000 elements. That thing you just heard fall on the floor is your call-stack. There is a time and place for recursion. This is neither. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: There is some beauty in a recursive algorithm for a recursive data structure. This is fine for applications with small lists.